# lambda function error: TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, lambda

I'm trying to execute the following [python notebook](https://github.com/DiceTechJobs/ConceptualSearch/blob/master/jupyter%20notebooks/Conceptual%20Search%20-%204.c%20Create%20Cluster%20Synonym%20Files.ipynb):

Them I came to the part where I have to use the function 'compute_cluster_similarities'.

```
def compute_cluster_similarities(kwds, kwd2id, vectors, lbl2centroid):
    kwd2cluster_sims = dict()
    for kwd in kwds:
        ix = kwd2id[kwd]
        nvec = vectors[ix]
        sims = []

        for lbl, centroid in lbl2centroid.items():
            cosine_sim = np.inner(nvec, centroid)
            sims.append((lbl,cosine_sim))
        sims = sorted(sims, key = lambda lbl,sim: -sim)
        kwd2cluster_sims[kwd] = sims
        if len(kwd2cluster_sims) % 1000 == 0:
            print("%i computed out of %i" % (len(kwd2cluster_sims), len(all_kwds)))
    return kwd2cluster_sims
```

And its returning the error:

> TypeError: () missing 1 required positional argument: 'sim'

First of all, I'm still trying to understand this part of the lambda code. I learned what is the objective of the lambda instruction but couldn't understand what is the point of this line of code, like.. is it (implicity) returning 2 values (sims, key)?? What is being sorted?

I think that this error is ocurring due the Python 3, but even if this was executed on Python 2, it doesn't make sense to me.
It's very confusing for me... How can I solve this error? And please, give me some explanation about what it's going on, not just the fix.

EDIT:
I'm using pdb library to debug the code and I realized that this error was being returned by the 'sorted()' function. The original error is:

> *** TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

What I did:

```
        cosine_sim = np.inner(nvec, centroid)
        sims.append((lbl,cosine_sim))
    import pdb ; pdb.set_trace();
    sims = sorted(sims, key = lambda lbl,sim: -sim)
```

and them at the Pdb mode:

```
(Pdb) sims, key = lambda lbl,sim: -sim
*** TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `key = lambda lbl, sim: -sim` is equivalent to `def key(lbl, sim): return -sim` but you can't put the latter into an expression.

Comment: but what about the 'sims' on 'sims, key = lambda lbl,sim: -sim'??

Comment: That has nothing to with the lambda. `sims` is passed to `sorted` because you want to sort it. The `key` argument tells it *how* to sort. You should read a tutorial about sorting in Python and maybe about functions and keyword arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in the `key` parameter of `sorted` is fetched with the elements of the list, therefore it accepts only one parameter.

If you substitute:

```
key = lambda lbl,sim: -sim
```

with:

```
key=lambda x: -x[1]
```

It should work as you expect.

Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sorted) for more explanation of how to use `sorted` and the `key` parameter.

Comment: But what is the point of the 'sims' variable?? Are it being overwrited? please see my edit

Comment: it is just used on the fly for sorting: you have a list of items where each item is itself a list and you want to sort them according the second element of the "inner" list, so instead of sorting the items, `sorted` sorts the result of `key` called on each element. The `sim` variable is meant to access that second element, but it will not work "as is".

Comment: so calling 'sorted(a,b)' is the same as 'sorted(a); sorted(b)'? Then what's the objetive of variable 'key' in this function? Where is this used?

Comment: no, it is not. Have you read: https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto (especially the `key functions` section)? `key` is not a `variable` it is a keyword argument passed to `sorted`, so it is used internally by it.

Comment: well... Finally realized that 'key' is a parameter of the Sorted() function. Thank you.

Comment: still don't know why people keep downvoting the question as it seems not so simple at the first look.

Comment: I think it is because it could have been formulated more clearly, for example by including a minimal working example showing the specific aspect that was unclear to you and not an excerpt from a larger code base that is more difficult to reproduce. Also, if you look back to the discussion, it boils down to Python syntax that was unclear to you, which is somewhat difficult to infer from the question, as it is currently written.